# Safari height: 100% issue

Tags: css, safari

Hoping someone can give me some insight on this. I've been setting up a component inside a bootstrap column. If I view it in Chrome and Firefox, the two images have the same height, but when I view in Safari, the images have different heights (the shorter image does not expand to the full height of the parent div). I've tried changing the height to auto, as well as using the bootstrap img-fluid class but nothing seems to work. I'm simply trying to get the image on the right to expand to the full height of the parent div. Does anyone have any ideas how to make this happen using only css?

Thanks in advance!

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="outer-div center">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Vbum3VZV9g0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="responsive inner-div" alt="Smiley face">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="outer-div center">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" class="responsive inner-div" alt="Smiley face">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mt-20 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.inner-div
{
    transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
    height: 100%;
}
.inner-div:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
.outer-div
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/hintonbradley/pen/ZmEYdb)

Answer (score 0):

try throwing this at it, I don't have access to a safari browser, so, fingers crossed:

css:

```
.row {
  display:flex;
}

.col-md-6 {
  align-self:stretch;
}

.outer-div
{
  display:flex;
}

.inner-div
{
  align-self:stretch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated. I’m trying not to use Flexbox too much as I’ve heard safari still has issues with it. If you could find a CSS solution without Flexbox that would be ideal. Otherwise, thanks for your help!